# Writing helper functions to C# DLL for reading a CSV file progressively from MFC parent application

Tags: c#, csv, mfc

One of my C# DLL functions reads a CSV file using CSvHelper. Eg:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(strPath))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<CLMExplorerStudent>();

    foreach (var record in records)
    {
    }
}
```

I have no problem with that. My MFC C++ project runs this method in the DLL and it opens teh CSV, parses it and does what is needed. Because evrything is managed by that one function internally.

---

But now I want to write some more functions in my DLL to break it down. Eg, in MFC:

```
dll->LoadCSV(path to csv)
for(dll->NextRow(row))
{
   MFC now does something with the row data
}
dll->CloseCSV();
```

Originally I thought that the DLL could just pass the read in data over to the MFC parent app but then I thought that not sensible approach. So I thought that it may be possible to get my DLL to open the CSV first, and then I can sequentially get the next row of data, until finished and then close the CSV. So no memory leaks.

But I am not sure how to turn the logic of my sample code into the 3 functions as it is using a `using` wrapper at the moment.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Have you considered using c++/cli? It may be fairly simple to add suport for this, and would make it fairly trivial to use .Net objects in c++.

Comment: @JonasH I already have my DLL help tool that I call from The MFC project (com interface) so I don’t want another really.

Comment: If you are using a COM interface it should be possible to return a COM wrapper you can use from c++, something equivalent to a IEnumerator in c#. But I have not used COM much, so I wont be of much help.

Comment: @JonasH I can certainly try that, but I would still have the issue that the current approach will close the CSV. I need to be able to open (step 1) read and return the contants for me to work with (step 2) and close when I am finished (step 3). Step 2 might be Ok by returning the IEnumerable of my class. But I still have step 1 and step 3 to look at too.

Comment: @JonasH I think for Step one I should add the objects as member variables and not use `using`. Then for step three, I would call `Dispose()` on each of those items. Step two would iterate the records one by one and return that object via COM API. If I get it to work I will put my code in an answer. Unless anyone has a better idea.

Comment: Actually probably easiest to read straight into a list. Then access by index. File will not be gigantic.